# The type or namespace name 'ListBoxItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I am just trying to add a selected item from a ComboBox to a ListBox, like this,

```
lboProveedoresSeleccionados.Items.Add(new  ListBoxItem
  (comboBox1.SelectedValue, comboBox1.SelectedText));
```

But i am getting this error "The type or namespace name 'ListBoxItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)", despite the fact that i have a reference already

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

Any idea? I know that i can just add the text, but i'm interested in have both, the values and the descriptions.

Comment: What kind of application it is WPF, Windows or ASP.NET?

Comment: Is this for a Windows Forms project?  If so, `ListBoxItem` is for WPF, not Windows Forms.  That would explain why `ListBoxItem` isn't being found--because your Windows Forms project by default has references to the System.Windows.Forms.dll but not to `System.Windows.Controls`.

Comment: Yes is a WindowsForm project, Is there anyway to do that on WindowsForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a Windows Forms project, you can't use the WPF `System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem`.  But note that `ListBox.Items` is an `ObjectCollection`, not specifically a `List<string>` or somesuch.  It will accept any type of object and display the result of calling `ToString()` on it.  So you could make a class with the data you need and add instances of that class to the `ListBox`.

Alternatively, if you want to use, e.g., some property of the object instead of `ToString()`, you can use the `DataSource` property and set the `ListBox's` `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

Comment: Very useful, i have done it like this:             `listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem);

            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "IdKeys";`